# Solving $e^{ix}=i$

Tags: calculus

I was assigned this problem: $$e^{ix}=i$$ I understand that with Euler's formula, $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$. I then set up the problem as $$i=\cos x +i\sin x$$ This means that $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x =1$. This works for $\frac{\pi}2$. It has to be multiplied $n$, so the answer should be $\frac{n\pi}2$.

This is how I did this problem. However, I believe it was marked as incorrect. Did I do something wrong? Is there another possible answer that I am missing? How should I go about solving a problem like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it has to be multiplied by $n$"? It clearly doesn't work for $x=\pi$. You instead should have $x=\pi/2+2\pi n$ because the trigonometric functions are periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: I see - I got the $\frac{\pi}2$ part, but I messed up on the $2\pi n$. That is how you take care of the fact that the function repeats itself over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the period wrong. The period of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ is $2\pi$.

Comment: And I multiplied instead of adding, right?

Comment: Yes, periods are added, not multiplied.

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{ix}=i=e^{\frac{iπ}{2}}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow e^{ix-\frac{iπ}{2}}=1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow e^{i(x-\frac{π}{2})}=1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x-\frac{π}{2}=2nπ$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x=2nπ+\frac{π}{2}$$

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos(x) = 0$ and $\sin(x)=1$, therefore
$$
x = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{ mod }2\pi
$$
Thus
$$
x= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.